# How can I write an out_cb handler in vim9script?

Tags: vim9script

In §9 of [`:h channel`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/channel.txt.html#channel) is mentioned the legacy vimscript `out_cb` handler.

```
let job = job_start(command, {"out_cb": "MyHandler"})
The function will be called with the channel and a message. You would define
it like this: 
    func MyHandler(channel, msg)
```

I tried this `def OutCb` function but got the following  message error :

```
  def OutCb(l: list<any>)
    # echomsg 'OutCb' .. string(l)
    # eval [][0]
  enddef

  def ExitCb(l: list<any>)
    # echomsg 'ExitCb' .. string(l)
    # sleep 1m
    # source += l
    # echomsg 'Exiting ' .. string(l) .. ' ' .. string(@z)
  enddef

  jobid = job_start(zip_cmd, { out_cb: OutCb, exit_cb:  ExitCb, mode: 'raw', timeout: 1200000 } )
```

Error message:

```
  This is a valid directory .
  Jobid: process 14328 run
  Press ENTER or type command to continue
  E118: Too many arguments for function: <lambda>4
```

How to port and deal with this in vim9 script that seems to have only one argument?

Comment: out_cb/exit_cb take 2 arguments not 1 list

Answer (score 1):

This is official answer of Bram Moolenaar, hope this can help someone.

> In Vim9 script the type of the arguments is checked.  That helps you
> writing correct functions, and once written it is easier to read back.
> It does require a bit of extra text.
>
> Here is an example that will help you:

```
vim9script

# Create a channel log so we can see what happens.
ch_logfile('logfile', 'w')

var shell_job: job

# Function handling a line of text that has been typed.
def TextEntered(text: string)
  # Send the text to a shell with Enter appended.
  ch_sendraw(shell_job, text .. "\n")
enddef

# Function handling output from the shell: Add it above the prompt.
def GotOutput(channel: channel, msg: string)
  append(line("$") - 1, "- " .. msg)
enddef

# Function handling the shell exits: close the window.
def JobExit(job: job, status: number)
  quit!
enddef

# Start a shell in the background.
shell_job = job_start(["/bin/sh"], {
                         out_cb: GotOutput,
                         err_cb: GotOutput,
                         exit_cb: JobExit,
                         })

new
set buftype=prompt
var buf = bufnr('')
prompt_setcallback(buf, TextEntered)
prompt_setprompt(buf, "shell command: ")

# start accepting shell commands
startinsert
```